# Easy-Game-Center Sprite-Kit Integration

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, game-center

I am trying to use the Easy-Game-Center by DaRkD0G from GitHub in my game (swift sprite kit). However, when calling the EasyGameCenter.Swift (using

```
        EasyGameCenter.sharedInstance(self)
```

in my GameScene) 
I get an error saying "Cannot convert value of type 'GameScene' to expected argument type 'UIViewController'". For the past couple days, I have tried changing up the different class types in EasyGameCenter but always get answers. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the creator of this project.

**You can't use the Game Center of Apple without UIViewController !**

The **Framework Game Center need UIViewController for work**, this is the official documentation of Game Center Apple.

[image]

**And Easy Game Center need create with delegate UIViewController for work perfectly, *without it is impossible to use Game Center***

**Example projet Game Center + Sprite Kit :**
http://www.raywenderlich.com/60980/game-center-tutorial-how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-sprite-kit-part-1

**Create instance with UIViewController :**

This is for create the instance of EasyGameCenter

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    EasyGameCenter.sharedInstance(self)

}
```

Add this, if you change UIViewController for notifies the view controller delegate was changed, it's optional if you not change UIViewController you do not need this method

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        EasyGameCenter.delegate = self
    }
```

just like that, now you can import the project with CocoaPods

```
pod 'EasyGameCenter', :git => 'https://github.com/DaRkD0G/Easy-Game-Center-Swift.git'
```

Comment: How would you bring up the Game Center Login screen at a specific point (if the user clicks a button that brings up a highscore and they are not logged in)?

Answer (score 1):

Never used that library, but as message says :

> "Cannot convert value of type 'GameScene' to expected argument type
>   'UIViewController'"

This is the method you are calling:

```
 class func sharedInstance(delegate:UIViewController)-> EasyGameCenter {
        if Static.instance == nil {
            dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
                Static.instance = EasyGameCenter()
                Static.delegate = delegate
                Static.instance!.loginPlayerToGameCenter()
            }
        }
        return Static.instance!
    }
```

You have to pass an UIViewController as an argument instead of GameScene.

Comment: does that mean I need to create a UIViewController to call the function and I cannot within a SKScene?

Comment: @SamAcquaviva Can't test it right now, but from the GitHub example, EasyGameCenter.sharedInstance(self) is called inside MainViewController class. I guess you are using GameViewController and its viewDidLoad (or viewWillLayoutSubviews) method to initialize the scene, right? So, set delegate there.

Comment: in viewDidLoad is for create the instance. 


in viewWillLayoutSubviews it's optional, is when you change UIViewController for set the new delegate UIViewController